# Javascript constructor with enumeration value as argument

Tags: javascript, constructor, module, prototype, enumeration

I would like to create an object that can take one of a fixed set of input strings as an argument in the constructor.  In order to constrain the possible strings, I would like to use an enumeration-type construction.

What I have so far is a solution that relies on two separate functions: one uses the Revealing Module pattern (I think) to expose the fixed set of strings, like this:

```
var MyEnum = (function() {
    var stringA = "string A";
    var stringB = "string B";
    var stringC = "string C";

    return {
        stringA: stringA,
        stringB: stringB,
        stringC: stringC
    };
})();
```

The second function takes as input one of the string values (along with other values) as arguments for construction.  For instance, given a function called MyObject, this is how I call it:

```
var myInstance = new MyObject(MyEnum.stringB, 42, "blue");
```

What I want to know is this:  Is there an alternate architecture that combines MyEnum and MyObject into a single entity?  MyEnum is not used by anything else, but it was the only way I could find to have the instances of the strings available to the MyObject constructor.

I tried somehow making the enumeration values available through a prototype method on MyObject, but the problem is that the method doesn't "exist" until the object is instantiated.

For background, I'm coming from the land of C#, so I know my thinking is biased in that direction, and maybe the solution is more psychological than technical.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** It's been pointed out the revealing module pattern is unnecessary here, which I understand and agree with.  That was a vestigial structure from an earlier attempt to solve this problem.  At this point, I don't know if it's preferable to edit the RM pattern out (since it's irrelevant to the question) or if this edit is sufficient.  I'd prefer to hide my shame, but I can also own a mistake...

Comment: `var MyEnum = {stringA: "string A", stringB: "string B"}` is exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach `static` properties to the function object:

```
function Painter(color) {

}

Painter.Color = {
    RED: "color_red",
    BLUE: "color_blue"
};

var painter = new Painter(Painter.Color.BLUE);
```

There no need for the revealing pattern when defining the enum, since you are exposing everything anyways.

Comment: Awesome!  Can you explain a little about where these values reside?  Are they "copied" for each instance of Painter?  (Also, the revealing module pattern was vestigial from a previous attempt to solve the problem.  I agree that it's not needed here.)

Comment: @Klay In Javascript, functions, such as `Painter` are also objects. Which means they can have properties, such as `prototype` or `Color`. The `prototype` is a special property which is attached to each instance, when using the function as a constructor. All other properties are simply normal properties, which are not copied for each instance. No different than `Painter = { Color: { etc.. } }`.

Comment: See here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 0):

If you want all this things encapsulated in the same object you can follow the approach **Everything is an object**

```
//constructor definition
function Contructor(arg1, arg2) {
  //use Contructor.values
  //implementation
}

//defines the set of values as a property of the constructor
Contructor.values = {
  stringA: "string A",
  stringB: "string B",
  stringC: "string C"
};
```

Or if you want pass it as an argument:

```
//constructor definition
function Contructor(value, arg1, arg2) {
  //implementation
}

var obj = new Contructor(Contructor.values.stringA, 42, "blue");
```